# Flutter design height of image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i am new to flutter and i am trying to make this screen:

What i have now is :

i tried everything to make the image look like the example but no success, played with containers height, AspectRatio. also i dont understand how to have empty space betwwen the price and zipcode like the example.

Hope someone can help me out. thanks all

Comment: Try giving the height to image.network widget itself

Comment: i tried but nothing changed.

Comment: @muhammedjasir do you have more ideas bro?

Comment: Use Row and Column instead of ListTile, That would work

Answer (score 0):

Card Design using Row and Column:

```
Widget customCard() {
  return Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://images.pexels.com/photos/106399/pexels-photo-106399.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-binyamin-mellish-106399.jpg&fm=jpg',
              height: 100.h,
              width: 100.h,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 13.w),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                '\$45,000',
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8.h),
              const Text(
                '1011KH Raamgrach',
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40.h),
              const Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // Use Row to show Icon with Text
                  Text(
                    'Bed : 1',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Bath : 1',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Area : 1',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Location : 1',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget for your images. Just change the image source and you can use it.

```html
  Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        elevation: 0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        semanticContainer: true,
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                        child: Image.network(
                          "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
```